# Javers: Store contextual informations on changes

Tags: javers

I am currently evaluating Javers on whether or not we could use it to audit our data.
We currently have an "in house" solution which is not doing the job.
However there is one functionality that I cannot find in Javers and I'm wondering if it's because I don't know how to look or if it is because it does not exist.

Is it possible, with Javers, to store contextual informations like, for example, the source of the change (manual change, event change...).
Our need is not just to identify what has been changed but also in what context.

What I have found so far, is the properties map that can be provided when commiting. But I'm wondering if you can add actual entities to the context and then be able to use Javers queries to search by context.

Example :

I have Entity1, Entity2 and Entity3:
* when I commit changes on Entity3, I add to the context Entity1
* when I commit changes on Entity2, I add to the context Entity1

I am then able to search all commits that have impacted Entity1 via this context.

I realize that this may be out of scope for an audit engine.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Commit properties is  String to String Map, nothing more

Comment: I'd also like to have a similar feature. I think it's reasonably in the scope of an audit engine the ability to know why or by what means did something change, and not only what that change was.

It would be great if JaVers would support this. 

In any case, It's definitely much better than my custom solution.